# How to construct a PrincipalPermission with Principal to authorize against that Principal's account?

Tags: c#, wcf, permissions

Question,

How can I construct a PrincipalPermission object that will authorize against data from a Principal object when I call Demand on PrincipalPermission?

Why and what have you tried...

I store account strings supplied by user input that reflect user account names like "jlaird". Then when someone tries to use my Windows service, I authorize access based on who is calling in via the WCF interface.

So I take supplied string and build a System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal object from it. This way:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal userP = null;
userP = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), "jlaird");
```

Then I build a System.Security.PrincipalPermission this way:

```
System.Security.PrincipalPermission permPP = null;
permPP = new PrincipalPermission(userP.UserPrincipalName, null);
```

Then when I call System.Security.PrincipalPermission.Demand() and wait for an exception (or not) to authorize the user that is calling the Windows service like this:

```
permPP.Demand()
```

By debugging, I verified that both strings "jlaird" and "MYDOMAIN\jlaird" point to the same account represented by the Principal object. In both cases the Principal objects have the UserPrincipalName of 'jlaird@MYDOMAIN.com'.

Demand on PrincipalPermission throws an exception even when I construct it from userP.UserPrincipalName. In fact, it only authorizes the user and does not throw an exception when I pass in the string "MYDOMAIN\jlaird" into new PrincipalPermission like:

```
new PrincipalPermission("MYDOMAIN\jlaird", null);
```

Yet, this will throw an exception:

```
new PrincipalPermission("jlaird@MYDOMAIN.com")
```

How can I construct a PrincipalPermission object that will authorize against data from a Principal object so that "MYDOMAIN\jlaird" and "jlaird" will authorize and make Demand not throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Found a solution.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wIdent = null; 
wIdent = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity(userP.UserPrincipalName);
System.Security.PrincipalPermission permPP = null;
permPP = new PrincipalPermission(wIdent.Name, null);
```

PrincipalPermission(string, string) expects the first argument to be a IPrincipal name that was the clue. WindowsIdentity implements that interface. So 'jlaird' and 'MYDOMAIN\jlaird' on my domain both end up resolving to 'MYDOMAIN\jlaird' which makes PrinicipalPermission.Demand happy.